# Multiprocessing Python

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I have a linux machine with 4 cpus.

I have a long running program that i need to execute concurrently on 1024 hosts and get the result back.

```
ipArrayList -> Contains list of host ips.
```

The below program runs fine but it takes a long time and sometimes it hangs for days:

```
import multiprocessing

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(100)
pool.map(long_running_module,ipArrayList)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The below program runs faster only in case of less input(size of ipArrayList). If the number of IPs in ipArray list is huge then sometimes I run into buffer space issues.([Errno 105] No buffer space available)

```
job = []
for ip in ipArrayList:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=long_running_module, args=(ip))
    job.append(p)
    p.start()

for j in job:
    j.join()
```

The long_run_module connects to each of the ip in the ipArrayList via ssh(paramiko). It does some long running calculation inside the host machine and then return the result to a synchronized list.

Kindly help me to effectively program this out.

Comment: I suspect that when you are overflowing the arguments buffer, though I'm not sure. Try sending in a list instead: `multiprocessing.Process(target=long_running_module, args=(ipArray,))`. Make sure to expect a list in your processing.

Comment: Why a pool of 100 on 4 CPUs?

Comment: Suggestion: use https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Comment: Suggestion: for python specific use [ipyparallel](https://ipyparallel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) . NOTE: pointing to the docs

Comment: @Reut: Actually i am passing a list. Edited the question

Comment: @Tichodroma: I thought multiprocessing.Pool(100) will start 100 process simultaneously and when any of the  process from the already started 100, would get free then only it will take up the next task. In the first case if i have 1000 ip in my ipArraylist it opens up 1000 process. But in second case it opens up 100 process and waits for completion before taking up further ips from the list. Well, this was my understanding when i wrote the program, But now i guess i am missing something biggie..

Comment: @Girish: i have to install this ipyparallel module before calling it. Unfortunately the limitation i have is my host is a vCenter and i cannot install any 3rd party modules and i am only to work with core python modules...

Answer (score 1):

I agree that using pool is not the best if you have just 4 cores, you can use "map" function instead, take a look to [this](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing_intro.html).

```
map(f, S)
```

**f** *is a function that takes one argument and returns a value.*

**S** *is any iterable.*

```
>>> def add100(x):
...     return x+100
... 
>>> map(add100, (44,22,66))
[144, 122, 166]
```

However as you need to execute concurrently on 1024 hosts and get the result back I highly recommend you to use a distributed platform. There are some of them in Python but [SCOOP](https://github.com/soravux/scoop/) is very well documented and maintained.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.